# Terminal x Software Center

Tags: command-line, software-center, gnome-terminal

I'm still a novice in Ubuntu, sorry if this was questioned before, what's the best way to install software on Ubuntu in terms of update, stability, etc: through terminal or through Software Center (if available)?

Comment: Nothing specific, its just that sometimes the developers recommend an installation method over the other.

Comment: For instance, the express vpn extension does not work if the browser (or at least Firefox) was installed through software center

Comment: I'm sure that the developer of that extension would like to know about that issue. Please [file a bug report](https://github.com/faidoc/gnome-shell-extension-expressvpn-manager/issues).

Comment: They know, there's a warning when you click on the extension. it was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... through terminal or through Software Center

Those are the same. For starting as a real novice you can always use the software center. It will have almost all you would need to install. Later on you will get to see command line instructions that do the same (Under the hood software center) uses `apt` so on command line `sudo apt install {package}` does the same. {package} can be found in the software center at the details of a package.

You will see this a lot in Linux: we have more than 1 method to do the same thing but command line is useful because it works on all Ubuntu versions. Plus the extra benefit is that you can put all those commands into a script so you can re-run that script after re-installing.

All software installed from `apt` will receive security and bug updates. We generally do not get newer versions of software as those come every new release.

Never install software from a random website unless you can verify the owner of that website. If for instance you want to use Chrome (instead of Firefox or Chromium) you can install it from their website since google can be trusted with that. It is also set up to start software center so it follows the Ubuntu way of installing. The same applies for the 2 main servers: webserver apache/nginx and database server mysql/mariadb. But those are for when someone is more experienced.

Comment: How about .deb packages, are they the same?

Comment: DEB.'s contain the -content- of what you install. And it is the tool you install it with that is important. if that is software center or apt it is the same.

Comment: Its way less confusing for me now, thank you.